# Change URL in component action

Tags: javascript, redirect, ember.js, components

I need change URL when "something" happens. So I made an action and when i call that action I want the change to happen:

```
export default Component.extend({
    // ... 

    actions: {
        test: function(){
            this.transitionTo("dashboard");
        }
    },

    testHandle: function()
    {
        this.send("test");
    },
});
```

I'm using ember 1.13. And after the start of the action script it throws this to the console:

```
Deprecations were detected, see the Ember Inspector deprecations tab for more details.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined(…)
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `Ember.Component` doesn't have a `transitionTo` method. You need to send an action from a component and handle it in controller. [Docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/)